# IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 developing an asp.net application with Javascript modules, each ajax request is queued

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, iis-7.5

I have looked around Google and StackOverflow for days and before you redirect me to a similar question, please read the post.

I am developing a website using asp.net and Javascript modules. Each of these modules sends out a get/post request to various servers to fetch data. The problem that happens is when I am deploying the application to IIS, each of these requests are queued instead of being executed simultaneously.

The same code, deployed on a local development server/AppHarbour works fine.

Before posting this question I have already tried the following things

1. Disabled the SessionState on the controllers.
2. Tweaked the machine.config file for ASP.NET
3. Changed the Application pool to behave as a web garden

Comment: Are the get/post requests initiated via javascript (i.e. in a browser) or by your code?

Comment: They are initiated by javascript.